# How to switch to a new remote repo in git?

Tags: git

I have been using GitHub for my remote repo and need to switch to bitbucket.  Currently, my local repo is synced with GitHub.  I tried the following:
To delete the association with the GitHub remote:

```
git remote remove origin
```

The bitbucket repo came with a `.gitignore` and `README.md` file.  I deleted both of these files on the bitbucket master repo.
To add the association with the Bitbucket remote:

```
git remote add origin https://me@bitbucket.org/dir/my_project.git
git push -u origin master
```

which resulted in:

```
To https:///me@bitbucket.org/dir/my_project.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https:///me@bitbucket.org/dir/my_project.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

So I thought I needed to do a git pull for some reason--eventhough I deleted everything on the bitbucket repo.
This resulted in:

```
git pull
warning: no common commits
remote: Counting objects: 8, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Total 8 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (8/8), done.
From https:///me@bitbucket.org/dir/my_project
 * [new branch]      master     -> origin/master
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master
```

Then I tried:

```
 git pull origin master
From https:///me@bitbucket.org/dir/my_project
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

I don't really know what I'm doing here.  Should I use the following?:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
```

If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bitbucket repository would be an entirely new repository, unrelated to your local repository. If there's nothing of value in your Bitbucket repository you can force push to the origin.

`git push --force --set-upstream origin master:master`

This will overwrite the origin's `master` with your local `master` and setup the remote-tracking branch. I've used the long version of the flags to be more explicit, but `-fu` would have done the same.